# How to configure a linux router so that DHCP is only used on one interface?

Tags: linux, networking, router, virtualbox, dhcp

I'm using Virtualbox for this lab.

I'm currently working on a project where we would like to have a Linux router to route traffic between multiple Virtual Machines. We also want the router to be able to hand out IP addresses using DHCP.

We only want DHCP to run on a single, internal interface on this router. The external facing interface will be used for access to the internet and will receive an IP address from a DHCP server on my LAN.

Currently, I have the router setup to forward packets and DHCP is setup to handle requests. I'm using IPTables to limit any traffic on ports 67/68 (DHCP) to our external interface.

My problem is that I obviously cannot receive an IP address on the external facing interface since there is an IPTables rule to block any traffic on ports 67/68.

Essentially, I'd like to setup DHCP so that it is only able to receive DHCP requests on a single interface. The external facing interface will receive an IP address from a DHCP server on my LAN.

Comment: It depends on what you use to carry out the DHCP service: dnsmasq, DHCPv4,... you should let us know.

Comment: Sorry - Using DHCPv4 on Centos 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using DHCPv4 on Centos 7

Then edit the file */etc/sysconfig/dhcpd* and make sure that there is a line like:

```
DHCPDARGS="eth0";
```

if *eth0* is the interface you want your DHCP server to listen on, otherwise change accordingly. Reboot or restart the service.

That`s all.

Comment: Is there anyway to confirm which interfaces DHCP is currently listening on?

Comment: *ss -lntp* for TCP protocol, *ss -lnup* for UDP protocol.

Comment: Hmm alright, thank you! This seemed to work for me (editing /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd) even though I tried it before and it didn't work.

I don't see any interfaces mentioned in ss/lnup, just a few different dhcp ahd dhclient connections but no associated interfaces. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @KoolAid The output of *ss* mentions the addresses the process is listening on; an address of the type \*:445 means the process is listening on port 445 on **all** interfaces, while an address of the type *192.168.1.1:53* menas the process is listening on port 53 for the **single** interface which has address 192.168.1.1 . This should allow you to check that everything works as per your wishes.

Comment: @KoolAid Ops, I forgot: and the command *ip addr show* will display which interface has which IP address.